# lidR grid_density report

Tags: lidr

When you use `d1 <- grid_density(las, res=5)` and `d2 <- grid_density(las, res=10)`

`d1` is a raster when each cell is the density per 5x5=25 square meters or density in 1 square meters ?
`d2` is a raster when each cell is the density per 10x10=100 square meters or density in 1 square meters ?
Because my result is different between `d1` and `d2` !
In fact how can i have a density in 1 square meters ?

Comment: By definition density is in pts/m². But to get a meaningful number your must define a minimal area to compute the density. If you have 1 pts/m² on average and you estimate the density within 1×1 cell you are likely to get only some 0 and 1. `grid_density` is only a wrapper around `grid_metrics(las, ~list(point_density = .N/res^2), res)`.

Comment: In this case why d1 is different of d2 ?

Comment: What do you mean by different? Please edit your question and show us an image for example.

Comment: i make a mistake in may d1 and d2 raster, there is in fact no problem ! Sorry .